# str_replace() escaping question marks in R with a vector from a SPDF, stringr package

Tags: r, stringr

I'm embarrased to ask this question but I have tried with `gsub` and now the `stringr` package.

I cannot get these string replacements done:

```html
str_replace(mexispdf@data$ADM1NAME,pattern = "M\\?xico",replacement = "México")
str_replace(mexispdf@data$ADM1NAME,pattern = "Nuevo Le\\?n" ,replacement = "Nuevo León")
str_replace(mexispdf@data$ADM1NAME,pattern = "San Luis Potos\\?",replacement = "San Luis Potosí")
str_replace(mexispdf@data$ADM1NAME,pattern = "Quer\\?taro de Arteaga",replacement = "Querétaro de Arteaga")
```

I thought the problem would be that `ADM1NAME` was a factor and not a character, so I changed it:

```html
mexispdf@data$ADM1NAME<-as.character(mexispdf@data$ADM1NAME)
```

But it still doesn't work:

[image]

The data are here: http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/povmap-small-area-estimates-poverty-inequality/data-download

Just download the Mexico shapefile.

Comment: Do you have a sample data using `dput(mexispdf)`? `str_replace` with escaping question mark works fine for me.

Comment: @Shique I just tried to use dput(mexispdf) but it had too many lines and Stack Overflow didn't accept it. Is there another way to export some data for a reproducible example without too many lines? Otherwise, it can be imported from here: http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/povmap-small-area-estimates-poverty-inequality/data-download click on Mexico and that's it!

Comment: I cannot download the data because it needs a registration to do so. Is it possible to create a `subset()` of the dataframe extracting only the needed column? You can then use `dput(head(subsetdf, 5))`

Comment: @Shique just did this again and even with `dput(head(subsetdf, 1)` I had 50,000+ lines of code. Any other ideas and I'll try them :) I know registering is a pain but on that site its free. Obvs not ideal.

Comment: Hmm, how about `dput(droplevels(head(subsetdf, 1)))`. This would be my final attempt

Comment: @Shique Thank you so much but it still didn't work because it said: Error in UseMethod("droplevels") : no applicable method for 'droplevels' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial', 'SpatialPolygonsNULL', 'SpatialVector')"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all("Is Nuevo Leon in Mexico?", 
                c("M.xico" = "México", "Nuevo Le.n" = "Nuevo León"))


# [1] "Is Nuevo León in México?"
```

Answer (score 0):

with `gsub` using the `fixed=TRUE` argument worked for me:

```
a = "M\\?xico"
gsub(pattern = "\\?",replacement = "é",a, fixed = TRUE)
# "México"
```

Comment: Hi @DrorBogin! I had already tried this and just did again and it doesn't work :-( but thank you anyway!

Comment: @ÁngelaGill However it works here. Give an example for which it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With `stringr` you can do

```
> str_replace_all("M\\?xico", pattern = c("[^M?xico]"="é", "[?]"=""))
[1] "México"
```

Comment: Hi Stéphane, this did this to it!  [16] "éoéoéé"               "éoéoéé"               "ééiéééééé"           
  [19] "éoéoéé"               "éoéoéé"               "éoéoéé"              
  [22] "éoéoéé"               "ééiéééééé"            "éoéoéé"

Comment: You mean that does not work ? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Yes! It didn't work and it changed most of the letters into 'é'.

Comment: @ÁngelaGill What about `str_replace_all("M\\?xico", pattern = c("\\\\"="é", "[?]"=""))` ?

Comment: Very close!!! It now returns this: "[979] "Mxico"                "Puebla"               "Michoacán de Ocampo" 
 [982] "Puebla"               "Hidalgo"              "Mxico"               
 [985] "Puebla"               "Hidalgo"              "Michoacán de Ocampo" 
 [988] "Puebla"               "Jalisco"              "Puebla"              
 [991] "Mxico" without the 'é'.

Comment: `str_replace_all(ct, pattern = c("\\\\"="é", "[?]"="é"))` should do it